# Convert JavaScript array with two values two decimal number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in Javascript `[37, 2]`.

How can I convert that array to a decimal number like `37.2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
+[37, 2].join('.')
```

or

```
parseFloat([37, 2].join('.'))
```

Comment: I'm wondering if this logic would hold up if the array had more indexes (I'm just thinking outloud). Also a note for anybody who doesn't know, the `+` is shorthand for casting as a number.